# Oracle APEX: Add list boxes on demand

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to APEX and was wondering if you could point me in the right direction.  I have an app that has 24 pairs of list boxes, (24 is the limit per requirements).  What I did was create and show all 24 and it looks weird.  ([See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wExyY.jpg)).
[image]

My question  is this:  Is there a way to have maybe just one pair show and as they make their selection, a new pair of list boxes appears?  Or maybe have a button that says something like "add a new category / type" and once clicked, a pair of list boxes is created?  This would go on until they've populated the 23 sets of list boxes since 24 would be the limit.

By the way, the selected category value drives the type value.  On the linked image, the size of the list boxes varies because of this.  Can those list boxes be made with a fixed width?

Oh, I'm using 4.2.

Comment: What has your research turned up so far?

Comment: Hey Newd, thanks for responding.  I haven't had much luck at all.  My searches have turned out more static controls than anything.  What would be a couple of key words to search for?

Comment: How did you build up your page? Are these all page items?

Comment: Create a Tabular Form on page which helpas to add row on demand.

Comment: Tom, yeah they are all individual page items.

Pars, thanks for that, i'll look into it.  How hard would it be to place a limit of 24 rows?

Comment: I should of also mentioned that the "Type" select list is a cascading LOV, where the parent is category.

Comment: Hide all rows, then run javascript function (with correct jquery selectors), which will show next row when current row changes. If you show html-source of your page, i will try to help you.

Comment: NoGotnu, I have been playing with this for a couple of days now.  I am new to this, but a coworker suggested that I use a report and add APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY for the select list.  I ran into a problem with that because I have 8 values for the select list "Category" and it's creating 8 select lists instead of one.  Each select list does have the 8 values.  Then I have to figure out the whole cascading lov.  Am i going about this the wrong way?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I should explain something else.  On the picture, where it says "Selected Accounts", a list of accounts should appear.  The values that they select from the select lists will be added to those accounts and new records created per selection.  This is why my coworker suggested the APEX_ITEM.  I could then loop through the array and create the new records.

Comment: Show the query of your report and show queries on select lists - i will try to help. Generally, i think using report is wrong way, because you mentioned that <<the "Type" select list is a cascading LOV, where the parent is category>>, and i don't know how to make report with cascading select lists. APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY have no parameters to link select lists. So, if you already has done the big work (added 24 x 2 select lists and added logic), continue with this way. When you will get working example, you may improve it later, if you want (make via report for example).

Answer (score 0):

Having read through the posts on this, if you did want to attempt creating a report which has cascading select lists you could try the approach found at this link:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=39514:1:

It's a slightly long winded process so it may not be the easiest solution, however having read through the instructions the guy provides it seems do-able:

https://apextipps.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/cascading-lov-in-tabular-form/

Hope that is of some help.